# Cannot get my chart to appear in Charts.WPF

Tags: wpf, charts, data-binding

I've been trying to get just a basic chart to appear in my WPF application.  Unfortunately the library I chose to go down this rabbit hole with happened to have very little documentation.  All I was able to find was this GitHub repository:

https://github.com/mendonca-andre/Charts.WPF

Here is the nuget package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Charts.WPF

Any time I google Charts.WPF google just thinks I am looking for any wpf library that can make charts.  That being said, I think I almost got this working, but I can't figure out how to bind data to the chart that it can interpret.  I looked in the example and found they were using ObservableLists, so I tried that, but that didn't work.

Here is my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Eartquake_Tracker.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:chart="clr-namespace:Charts.WPF.ChartControls;assembly=Charts.WPF"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Eartquake_Tracker"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:BuildGraph x:Key="functions"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource functions}"/>
    </Grid.DataContext>

    <chart:ChartSeries SeriesTitle ="La Palma Quakes" Width="300" Height="300" ItemSource="{Binding Path=chartData}"/>
</Grid>
```

Here is the class I am trying to bind it to.  The data I am using right now, is just linear data I am trying to get to appear:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Eartquake_Tracker
{
    class BuildGraph : System.Windows.Data.DataSourceProvider
    {
        public Dictionary<int, int> chart = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        public ObservableCollection<Dictionary<int, int>> chartData = new ObservableCollection<Dictionary<int, int>>();

        public BuildGraph()
        {
            //this.chartData = chartData;
            chart.Add(0, 0);
            chart.Add(1, 1);
            chart.Add(2, 2);
            chart.Add(3, 3);
            chart.Add(4, 4);
            chart.Add(5, 5);

            chartData.Add(chart);

        }
    }
}
```

If anyone is familiar with this library any help would be appreciated, maybe familiarity with making charts in general would be helpful here.  I am not very familiar with WPF and binding and charts.  Thanks for the help!

[image]

Comment: do you have binding errors (I would expect some)? How are you setting the `DataContext` of the `Window`? Your `chartData` field needs to be a property i.e. `{ get; set; }`.

Comment: I had 0 binding errors.  Which I assume means it was seeing the data, even without the {get; set}, because it's public.  Maybe it's not a good coding practice, but I am just trying to get it to work at the moment.

Comment: I added an image of the running app.  It shows 0 binding failures.

Comment: Apologies, don't know how I missed the `DataContext` being set in xaml

Comment: So added the {get; set;} to the chartData and I still am not seeing anything

Comment: Are you sure you want an ObservableCollection of Dictionary? What happens if you bind to `chart` instead of `chartData`

Comment: The only reason I made it ObservableCollection, is because in the example I saw them doing that.  Originally it was bound to just the list, and I still wasn't seeing anything.  Perhaps I should just switch to a library with better documentation.

Comment: What kind of chart are you wanting to create?

Comment: @JMC0352 , did you get the charts working? Please use the examples in the GitHub repo.

Comment: @AndreMendonca Yes, but not with this library.  I had to switch to a completely different library that worked.  I didn't want to switch, because I was so close with the current library, but nothing I did could get it to work.  So I believe I ended up using WPFToolKit.DataVisualization.  I had to start from scratch, but I eventually got it working.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this to work by looking at the examples in the git repo. If I were you I would download the repo and have a play. There is a generic.xaml file that shows how to create each different type of chart.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:charts="clr-namespace:Charts.WPF.ChartControls;assembly=Charts.WPF"
        xmlns:pieChart="clr-namespace:Charts.WPF.Core.PieChart;assembly=Charts.WPF"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <pieChart:PieChart ChartTitle="Test" ChartSubTitle="Test" ChartLegendVisibility="Visible">
            <pieChart:PieChart.Series>
                <charts:ChartSeries
                                    SeriesTitle="Test"
                                    DisplayMember="Text"
                                    ValueMember="Value"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=chart}">
                </charts:ChartSeries>
            </pieChart:PieChart.Series>
        </pieChart:PieChart>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

It's easier if you use your `Window` as the `DataContext`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public Dictionary<int, int> chart { get; set; } = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        chart.Add(1, 1);
        chart.Add(2, 2);
        chart.Add(3, 3);

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Be aware though that this will only work if you add all your values to the dictionary before calling `InitializeComponent`. This is because the `Dictionary` isn't observable i.e. your view won't be notified when items are added or removed.

Hopefully this gives you enough to investigate the other types of graph.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for the reply.  I'll look into that right now, and follow up soon.

Comment: So I am seeing the chart header, but no chart.  Is that what you got?

Comment: Why does no one look at the examples in the git repo? Hahaha Contains a complete working example with all the charts.

Comment: @AndreMendonca I did look at the git repo.  That's the point.  They were still not working.  That was the issue.  I even made a follow up comment, and the OP never replied.  This library was not working, no matter what I did.